# TypeError in Multiprocessing threads Python/ encoding

Tags: python, multithreading, encoding, python-multithreading

I have a list in python which looks like that:

```
>>> print chunked_fsq_ids
[u'4bee84983686c9b6b794246e', u'4cbfb9f10d22ef3bc4e12c70', u'4b570230f964a520aa2228e3', u'51fd214d454ab82ac66e1211', u'4baf22eef964a5201ced3be3']
```

I want to create a multi threaded proccess:

```
def getter(id):
    print id 


for fsq_id in chunked_fsq_ids:
    t = threading.Thread(target=getter, args=( fsq_id ))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
map(lambda t: t.join(), threads)
```

However I recieve a (looped) TypeError:

```
Exception in thread Thread-461:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: getter() takes exactly 1 argument (24 given)
```

Each `fsq_id` is 24 characters so it's like I am giving a list.

Do I have some trouble with the encoding or I miss something from the threding? The `fsq_id` is `Unicode`. However i bump onto the same error even if I `str(fsq_id)` or `fsq_id.encode('utf-8'). Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing trailing `,`:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=getter, args=(fsq_id,))
```

Following is interpreted as: 
    `t = threading.Thread(target=getter, args=('4', 'b', 'e', 'e', '8', '4', '9', '8', '3', '6', '8', '6', 'c', '9', 'b', '6', 'b', '7', '9', '4', '2', '4', '6', 'e'))`:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=getter, args=('4bee84983686c9b6b794246e'))
```